# Stretch <canvas> to fill flex item without any scrollbars

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap 5 and trying to set up a nested flex layout that fills the window, with one flex item filled by a "stretchy" `<canvas>` (so no scrollbars anywhere).

For some reason, creating the canvas with `w-100` and `h-100` utilities (equivalent to setting CSS width and height to 100%) is creating a vertical scrollbar on the page. I've seen numerous similar questions around the interwebs, but they almost all deal with `flex-direction: row` and don't seem to work for my `column` scenario. I can't tell if this is a bug in Bootstrap, or if I'm just misunderstanding nested flex containers and/or canvases.

Here is a Codepen that reproduces the issue: https://codepen.io/Rabadash8820/pen/eYWwXxx

And here is the HTML body:

```html
<body class="d-flex flex-column vh-100">

  <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
    Alert alert!
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Warning"></button>
  </div>

  <header>
    Header content
  </header>

  <div class="flex-grow-1 d-flex">
    <div class="flex-grow-1 d-flex flex-column">
      <main class="flex-grow-1 bg-dark">
        <canvas class="d-block w-100 h-100"></canvas>
      </main>
      <footer>Footer content</footer>
    </div>
    <div class="w-25"><h2>Options</h2></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you add all necessary CSS ?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I do not have any additional CSS. I've been able to meet all my styling needs with Bootstrap utility classes so far (e.g., `d-flex` and `w-25`).

Comment: Remove the `w-100` and `h-100` from `<canvas class="d-block w-100 h-100">` and it works fine. Don't ask me why, though. Trial and error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Switch from the default `min-height: auto` to `min-height: 0` for your flex items to suppress the minimum content size of your `canvas`.**

You’re seeing the scrollbars because when you set `width: 100%` on `canvas`, it tries to maintain its 2:1 aspect ratio, which affects its height. That height is communicated to the parents of `canvas`, which are flex items inside flex containers. By default, flex items don’t shrink below their `min-content` size, which is affected by the aspect ratio.

To prevent this from happening, you can set `min-height: 0` on your `<div class="flex-grow-1 d-flex">` and `<main class="flex-grow-1 bg-dark">` elements, like this:

```
<div class="flex-grow-1 d-flex" style="min-height: 0;">
  <div class="flex-grow-1 d-flex flex-column">
    <main class="flex-grow-1 bg-dark" style="min-height: 0;">
      <canvas class="d-block w-100 h-100"></canvas>
    </main>
    <footer>Footer content</footer>
  </div>
  <div class="w-25"><h2>Options</h2></div>
</div>
```

Then, they will let their flex containers shrink them, and then your `canvas` settings of `100%` `width` and `height` will refer to that shrunk size.

If you don’t want to write custom CSS, I guess the solution would be to find Bootstrap classes that correspond to setting `min-height: 0`.

Comment: Fantastic answer, thank you! Adding those `min-height` stylings (with a custom CSS class) fixed the sizing and removed the scrollbars! Out of curiosity, would it be more appropriate to use `flex-shrink` in there somewhere, rather than `min-height`? I'm still kinda new to flex layout so idk if this solution is hacky or typical :P

Comment: @Rabadash8820 I’d say this solution is typical in the sense that everything has its default behavior, and we step in and say we don’t want the default. So the default behavior for flex items is that they shrink (with the initial `flex-shrink: 1`), but they try to “protect” the content inside of them and not shrink below that (that’s the `min-height: auto` part). The non-obvious part here may be that the `canvas` element first contributes to the content size of its parent, and then sets its content size to 100% of the parent. So we need to “ignore” `canvas` first, and then have it sized...

Comment: @Rabadash8820 this would be really difficult to debug without the built-in layout inspector in Firefox DevTools. It’s the only browser that communicates more info about all that shrinking and content sizing!

Comment: Thanks for all the explanation. I definitely did not realize that `canvas` has all these caveats with sizing. I'll have to give those Firefox DevTools a try!